# Why Apache camel mina2 route uri raised exception?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, mina

Here is the `SyslogServerRoute` based on `org.apache.camel.spring.SpringRouteBuilder` wrapper. Where we need to run two services those are as following:

```
@Component
public class SyslogServerRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
         from("mina2:tcp://0.0.0.0:1235?sync=false&textline=true&sslContextParameters=#sslContextParameters").process(new Processor(){
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, DateUtil.format(new Date(), "yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
            }
        }).convertBodyTo(String.class).to("file:{{user.home}}/.chorke/var/audit/tcp?fileName=${file:name}.xml");

        from("mina2:udp://0.0.0.0:1234?sync=false&textline=true&sslContextParameters=#sslContextParameters").process(new Processor(){
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, DateUtil.format(new Date(), "yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
            }
        }).convertBodyTo(String.class).to("file:{{user.home}}/.chorke/var/audit/udp?fileName=${file:name}.xml");
    }
}
```

During the execution of **JUnit** test cases as following config:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = BootstrapApplication.class)
public class GetDocumentsTest implements HL7V3Constraint {
    @Test
    public void query() throws Exception {
       //TODO
    }
}
```

Cause following exceptions:

```
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1302)
    at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.acquire(Semaphore.java:312)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioDatagramAcceptor$Acceptor.run(NioDatagramAcceptor.java:168)
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How do we could overcome such type of `InterruptedException` to avoid concurrency?

Comment: At what time do you get that exception? Maybe its when your unit test is done and its shutting down, and as part of that it interrupts the mina thread.

Comment: You are right! At the end of **JUnit** execute. When it's going to shutting down.

Comment: Okay you should likely just ignore that. Apache Mina could maybe log those interrupts exception less noisy, or in a DEBUG level only. But try to run your app in a prod like setting and see how it shutdown when you stop the application.

Comment: For production it working fine!